# Upgrading Keycloak version from 16 to 18 , but database not getting migrated to latest version

Tags: keycloak, upgrade

We were trying to upgrade the keycloak version to latest from version 10 , we were able to upgrade till 16 version but we were not able to upgrade post 16

Note: we were running keycloak on kubernetes

we tried installing CR for keycloak custom resource
ref: https://www.keycloak.org/operator/realm-import.html

error: error: resource mapping not found for name: "realm-kc" namespace: "" from "keycloak-realm-import.yml": no matches for kind "KeycloakRealmImport" in version "k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
Note : Not able to find CRD for apiversion V2

Comment: hope you installed the CRD in proper namespace.